# .htaccess get the base part of the uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are few developers working each on a local `Apache` server.

We set some basic rules regarding the structure of our local development environment since we want to have one .htaccess file that will work for all.

The structure is pretty simple:

localhost/~username/api/api_request_request

I'm trying to create a RewriteRole that will store in custom variable the /~username/ part, since it varies from one developer to another.

This is what i got so far:

```
   #Set the base in case of local development
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)localhost(.*)$
   #Here only the /~username should be captured
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [E=LOCAL_BASE:$1]

   #Set the base in case of local development
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)localhost(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [E=LOCAL_BASE:production.server.com]

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/%LOCAL_BASE/api/index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

The problem is that in the first RewriteCond I don't know how the capture only the ~username part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a less complicated logic

```
# LOCAL environment
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/api/index.php?request=$2 [L]

# REMOTE environment
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /production.server.com/api/index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you please expend more about $1 and $2 ?
In addition, the difference between the production server and our development localhost is that in the development it looks like localhost/~username/api/apirequest and production is production.server.com/apirequest. i wanted to create a base variable that will include the base before /apirequest and will include the HTTP_HOST (just because I want it more generic), and I wonder I can make your example more generic

Comment: In first rule, `$1` captured `~username` and `$2` what's after. For instance, when you're on local, if you go to `http://localhost/~test/something/random/here` you'll have `$1` as `~test` and `$2` as `/something/random/here`, which will internally rewrite to `/~test/api/index.php?request=something/random/here`. Actually you can define a base in a more generic way but it's complicated for nothing. If you really want it, i can give you an example anyway

Comment: lurman thanks for the details. I the first rule, how do you define, or where do you set which part will go to each one of the variables ? I think that what i'm missing

Comment: Sorry i should have explained better. Actually, the pattern `([^/]+)` means *capture at least one character which is not a slash*. Let's take back my first example: if i go to `http://localhost/~test/something/random/here` then `RewriteRule` will receive `~test/something/random/here`. The first capture will be *at least one character which is not a slash* which means it will capture `~test`. Then, i specified there is a slash, and after it, i want to capture anything left. Hope you get it now

Comment: every time you put expression in brackets it will go to a $ variable? the first of () will be $1 the second $2 and so on ?

Comment: Yes until 9 (last possible). More info about *mod_rewrite* http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: ok that important knowledge.. I found out something weird. First of all I added RewriteBase / but when I ran your example it didn't worked. So I tried RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/api/index.php?request=$1 [NC,QSA,L], and when I tested it with [R=301] (so I could see the $1) I saw that when calling localhost/~asafnevo/api/sometext, $1 was equal to "sometext". which made me wonder, in the Rewrite rule, from where does it starts to compare the text to the regular expression ?

Comment: To be more specific, in the request from localhost/~asafnevo/api/sometext , why does the regular expression is being tested only on "sometext"

Comment: Looks like your htaccess is in `api` folder. To make it work as my example, you should put your htaccess in root folder

Comment: Thats true and actually makes complete since. Is there a way to rewrite a rule relative to the current .htaccess location? Without Rewritebase? Because if i do rewrite i have the ~username problem again, and if not it try to go to my computer root

Comment: Well if you want to capture the username, you have no choice but to put your htaccess in root folder. A good habit is to set `RewriteBase` with *the folder where your htaccess is*. For instance, if htaccess is in root folder: `RewriteBase /`. If your htaccess is in `example` folder: `RewriteBase /example/`. And, in all your `RewriteRule`'s, don't use a leading slash since the base (the one you defined with `RewriteBase`) will be appended to it